# Pagination fragment using servletUriComponentsBuilder within Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot 3.1.4 with Maven and Java 17, working on Wim Deblauwe's book called #Taming Thymeleaf. I've reached page 249 and I am now trying to implement pagination. Although I managed to successfully display the pagination summary, I've been unable to create the **urlBuilder** variable at the top of the pagination.html fragment, which is essential to manipulate to URL links so as to feed the pagination buttons:

`<div th:fragment="controls" class="bg-white px-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-between border-t border-gray-200 sm:px-6"   th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder)}">`

As soon as I try to include the above line as *th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org....)}"* to load **ServletUriComponentsBuilder**, and I rebuild my fragment (npm run build && npm run watch),the Chrome browser hangs. I've got to remove this line, only leave the class attribute and reload the fragment to get back to normal. When I go to the Spring boot stack trace, I notice the following error:

at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.EvaluationException: Access is forbidden for type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.servleturicomponentsbuilder' in this expression context.

I first looked at pom.xml to check whether I missed any dependencies. My pom.xml is in accordance with Wim Deblauwe's GitHub source code for chapter 10 minus some adaptations of my own: I am using MySQL instead of Postgres, I am neither using jpearl nor flyway. The following dependencies were added to my pom.xml to allow the call to ServletUriComponentsBuilder in the Thymeleaf pagination.html fragment:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

These dependencies additions to pom.xml did not help at all. Thanks in advance for helping me find a way to load the ServletUriComponentsBuilder in the pagination.html fragment without any error.

[My pagination so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAKof.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a change in Thymeleaf 3.1.2 that introduced this unfortunately.

As a workaround, you can define a wrapper class like this in your own code:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

public class ServletUriComponentsBuilderWrapper {

  public static ServletUriComponentsBuilder fromCurrentRequest() {
    return ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest();
  }
}
```

Then replace this:

```
th:with="urlBuilder=${T(org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder)}"
```

with (Suppose you created the class in the `com.mycompany.myproject.infrastructure.web` package):

```
th:with="urlBuilder=${T(com.mycompany.myproject.infrastructure.web.ServletUriComponentsBuilderWrapper)}"
```

I opened [an issue with Thymeleaf](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/977) but got no further information so far.

Comment: Yes, the suggested workaround solves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark the question as resolved by using the checkmark so other people know this question is answered now.